# Getting out of memory error while reading parquet file in spark submit job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 8]SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[Stage 1:=====================================================>   (43 + 3) / 46]17/11/16 13:11:18 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 54)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/11/16 13:11:18 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-4,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/11/16 13:11:18 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 54, localhost): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my code-

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    //sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", "true")
    log.setLevel(Level.INFO)
    val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val newDataDF = sqlContext.read.parquet(file)
    newDataDF.registerTempTable("newDataDF")
    //sqlContext.cacheTable("newDataDF")
    val result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rec FROM newDataDF")
    val rows = result.map(t => t(0)).collect()
    //val rows = result.map(t => t.getAs[String]("rec"))
```

It throws out of memory at below line
//val rows = result.map(t => t(0)).collect()

Have tried all options of memory tuning and increasing executor/driver memory increase, but nothing seems to work. 
Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by calling `collect` on your `DataFrame`, you tell Spark to gather ALL data onto the driver. For larger datasets this will indeed drown the driver and cause OOMs.

Spark is a framework for distributed computing intended to be used on large dataset that will not fit on a single machine. Only in very few cases do you ever want to call `collect` on a `DataFrame` and that is when you do debugging (on small datasets) or you *know* that you dataset has been reduced vastly in size due to some filtering or aggregation transformations.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree that a call to collect on a DataFrame would bring all data onto the driver. Since I am reading a parquet file, which is large in size, is there any other way to read the large sum of data and not gather all data on driver? Is there any other method or function i can call to gather the large set of data and not overload the driver? Or any other way I can do that? Thanks in advance if you have any solutions.

Comment: Well, what did you want to do with the data on the driver? I assume you need to do some querying?

Comment: Yes, i want to query and fetch all the data from a parquet file and then store it in hbase tables. Let me know if you have any thoughts on that. Thanks again.

Comment: In that case, you need to call `write` instead of `collect`.

Comment: write is used to write the data. I need to read all the data and do something with that. That is the reason I used collect. Can also use filter, but my use case is to read/collect all the data.

Comment: Spark is lazy evaluated and it only starts executing when you call an action. `write` is such an action - `read` is _not_. When you call `write` (or any other action such as `count` or `collect`) it triggers evaluation of all transformation preceding the action.

Answer (score 1):

you have to increase `spark.driver.memory` which default value is 1gb. you can check the driver and executor memory using --verbose command. For more information check this link and set the memory as per your requirement. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way by which i can source the spark conf file at the time of running the job from commandline and also without specifying the driver memory in commandline? Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: yes, you can set the memory at run time. example shown in above link.